# Cannot get C++ class function to return

Tags: c++, list, class, object, return-value

I am trying to use c++ programming to implement a class that I had already implemented in java and Python. I am trying to compare how this particular class will fare among the three languages. Basically what the class does is to generate random numbers after which it will store a series of unique random numbers in a list and then return the list which will later be sent of to another function for processing.However i am stuck with returning this list. I have created a header file with the necessary class declarations and putting the implementations in another source file. I have tried to run this program in my main method but after compiling successfully, the program just runs to infinity without executing the method meant to return and shows no error. I must add that i have only just started learning c++.

Below are extracts from my code:

Header File:

```
#ifndef LOTTOGENERATORHEADER_H
#define LOTTOGENERATORHEADER_H

#include<list>
#include<map>
#include<ctime>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

class LottoGenerator {
    std::list<int> lottoListReference;
public:
    LottoGenerator(void);
    int generateRandomNumber(int maxNum);
    std::list<int> generateLottoNumbers(int, int);
    void lottoNumberOccurrences(std::map<int, int> &seriesContainer, std::list<int> &LottoNumbers);
    std::map<int, int> sortedByValue(std::map<int, int> &sortedmap);
};
#endif

/* LOTTOGENERATORHEADER_H */
```

source file:

```
#include "LottoGeneratorHeader.h"
#include<iostream>



LottoGenerator::LottoGenerator() {
    srand(time(NULL)); 
}

int LottoGenerator::generateRandomNumber(int maxNum) {
    return rand() % maxNum + 1;
}

std::list<int> LottoGenerator::generateLottoNumbers(int noOfBalls, int maxLottoNumber) {
     std::cout<<"set me"<<"\n";
    if (!LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.empty())
        LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.clear();
    int rand = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfBalls; i++) {
        rand = generateRandomNumber(maxLottoNumber);
        if (std::find(LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.begin(), LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end(), rand) != LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end()) {
            LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.push_back(rand);
        } else {
            while (std::find(LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.begin(), LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end(), rand) == LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end()) {
                rand = generateRandomNumber(maxLottoNumber);
            }
            LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.push_back(rand);
        }
    }
    return LottoGenerator::lottoListReference;
}
```

Main method:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "LottoGeneratorHeader.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    LottoGenerator l;
    cout << "check0" << endl;
    std::list<int> generatedLottoNumbers = l.generateLottoNumbers(5, 50);
    cout << "check1" << generatedLottoNumbers.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**NB**:My implementations were deliberately made to be as similar as possible in all three languages

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces actually random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger to see what it is doiung

Comment: `std::find(LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.begin(), LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end(), rand)` will always return `LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end()` if `LottoGenerator::lottoListReference` is empty. Hence, in the first iteration of `for (int i = 0; i < noOfBalls; i++)` `while (std::find(LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.begin(), LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end(), rand) == LottoGenerator::lottoListReference.end())` is an infinite loop, since you don't modify `LottoGenerator::lottoListReference` in any way.

Comment: i think you have your 2 finds backwards - the first one should be == end (ie rand not found), the second one != end (ie makes new rands till we find a good one)

Comment: +1 to u guys. I did not realize that I had not added any int toLottoGenerator::lottoListReference  b4 starting the iteration causing program to enter an infinite loop. Thank you guys.